# Family $(X_y,D_y)$ with trivial canonical bundles

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ct.category-theory, complex-geometry, divisors

Let $i:D\hookrightarrow X$ and $f : X \to Y$ be holomorphic mappings of complex manifolds
such that $i$ is a closed embedding and $f$ as well as$ f \circ i$ are proper and smooth and $D$ is a divisor. Then a holomorphic family $(X_y,D_y)$ are the fibers $X_y=f^{-1}(y)$ and $ D_y=(f \circ i)^{-1}(y)$. 
First question:

> Let our family $(X_y,D_y)$ are have trivial canonical bundles. Is such
>   moduli space is non-uniruled?. Such moduli space exists?

Comment: I cannot parse your question.  Would you please clarify what you are asking?

Comment: You can see the paper of moduli of framed manifolds, Georg Schumacher page 237. But my question is about family $(X_y,D_y)$ which have trivial canonical bundles instead polarized canonical bundle

Comment: you don't think my question is clear now?